# how to destructure an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an object "data" from 'https://randomuser.me/api/' which I'm using in my project.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "female",
      "name": {
        "title": "miss",
        "first": "mia",
        "last": "sutton"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I destructured results from the data object as follows;
`const {results} = data;`
How do I destructure the results variable I created, and obtain the first item from it I want the de-structured array item to be declared as profile. This represents the profile data for the user gotten from the API call that I want to display in my app.

Comment: `const {results: [{name: {title, first, last}}]} = data;` This will completly destructure the first item on your list.

Comment: Thank you. How about if I want to give the first item in the array a name. For example `myArray`. So when I log `myArray`, I should get; ` {
      "gender": "female",
      "name": {
        "title": "miss",
        "first": "mia",
        "last": "sutton"
      }`

Comment: @Gm Emmy, this my answer below, I give an example of how to destructure the first item in the array, and go deeper if you need to

Comment: @GmEmmy Jo_va gave some examples for destructuring your object. If you just want to have your first element in an variable, simply use `const {results: [firstPerson]} = data;`

Comment: @Seblor Does the `firstPerson` represent the array item's new variable name?

Comment: `firstPerson` is an arbitrary name that will hold the first object in the list. You can name it however you want / need. Destructuring declares variables. the naming is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question, the solution doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this:

```
const { results: [firstItem] } = data;
```

See [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more info on destructuring.

```js
const data = {
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "female",
      "name": {
        "title": "miss",
        "first": "mia",
        "last": "sutton"
      }
    }
  ]
};

// declare a const variable named firstItem that holds the first element of the array
const { results: [firstItem] } = data;
// You could event destructure the content of this first array item like this
const { results: [{ gender, name }] } = data;
// or go deeper like this
const { results: [{ name: { title, first, last } }] } = data;

console.log(firstItem);
console.log(gender);
console.log(name);
console.log(title, first, last);
```

According to your code (see comments), this should work too:

```js
const data = {
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "female",
      "name": {
        "title": "miss",
        "first": "mia",
        "last": "sutton"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
  if(!data) return;
  const { results } = data;
  const { results: [profile] } = data;

  console.log(profile);
}

displayUserPhotoAndName(data);
```

Comment: @Gm Emmy, is this example working for you ? `const { results: [firstItem] } = data;`

Comment: No it's not unfortunately.

Comment: ` const displayUserPhotoAndName = (data) => {
        if(!data) return;
        const {results} = data;
 const {results: [profile]} = data;}`
I'm doing it inside a function that receives `data` as it's parameter.

Comment: @Gm Emmy, your error must be somewhere else, there is nothing wrong with that code. I updated the answer and added a snippet with your code and it works